# getting into the next element from the currently clicked element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple link structure (refer below)

```
<a href="#" class="bxxa">link 1</a>
<div class="errors"></div>
<a href="#" class="bxxa">link 2</a>
<div class="errors"></div>
```

and a jquery script (refer below)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxxa').click(function(){
        $('.errors').hide();
        $(this).next('.errors').show();
        $(this).next('.errors').html('<a href="#">column name itemname from row 2</a>');
    });
});
```

as you can see from the code above, if one of the link (.bxxa) is clicked, it will then first hide all the .errors div and then show the .errors div that was next to the current clicked .bxxa link and then add the add html inside on it but sadly not working, why?? any ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations, help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it's working fine http://jsbin.com/halewa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: i didn't get it!, it's working fine!

Comment: im still looking around my code, maybe theres a conflict around